# Designing database: Linking lots of values between tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Not worded my question very well, but with these tables:

```
    USER TABLE                       ANIMALS
    u_id   username                   a_id   animal
    --------------------------       ---------------------------
      2    alice                       1    cat
      4    brian                       2    small dog
      7    carla                       3    big dog
                                       4    rabbit
                                       5    guinea pig
                                       etc.
```

I want a user to be able to add however many animals they own to their profile.

What new tables/fields and datatypes would be the best way for me to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to allow multiple types of the same animal per user (Janet can have more than one Rabbit) then do the following.  Make UserId and AnimalID your primary key.

I would just do

```
 UserAnimals
 ------------
 UserId
 AnimalID
```

Filled with data your table might look like this:

```
 UserAnimals
 ------------
 UserId || AnimalId
      4 || 3
      4 || 2
      7 || 4
```

Brian has a small dog and a big dog.  Carla has a rabbit.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
A flaw in my example is you can only have one type of animal.

I considered using a table like you said (minus the quantity field) but won't there be a lot of redundant data especially if it's a very big table?
Is there no efficient way of doing a table sort of like this:

TABLE NAME - UserAnimals.
FIELD - User_ID (Eg Value: "4").
FIELD - Animal_IDS (Eg Values: "1, 2, 5").

Comment: That's exactly what my answer is...without the Quantity column.  I'll modify my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you but what I meant is, isn't there a more efficient way to store all the Animal IDs in one field? As a sort of array?
That way I only have to store (or when searching for, find) the User ID once.

Comment: You could store the AnimalId as a string, but how I have it for you is the correct method.  The problem with doing it as a string is you have nothing to Join onto the Animal table with.

Comment: http://johniekarr.blogspot.com/2011/08/pushing-multiple-results-into-one.html This link will show you how to get all your animals in one column when you do your query.  I wrote the article for SQL Server and I haven't used MySql in a really long time so I don't know if it will work or not, but it might get you started in the right direction.

Comment: I'll do it this way but I always assumed there would be a more efficient way to do it, though this is the most straight forward way I guess.
Thanks again for your help and the link too, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem.  Could you mark this as the answer if it answered your question?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you need a table which will map user ids to animal ids.
If you want to add them 1 at a time, you could just use a table like so:

```
UserAnimals
-----------
UserID (fk to User Table)
AnimalId (fk to Animal Table)
```

Assuming they might own, say 3 dogs, and you want to track the number, you could either have a row per animal or you could modify the table to include a count of the animals of each type:

```
UserAnimals
-----------
UserID
AnimalID
Count
```

I'd probably do it that way if I knew that there was a good chance that folks would have multiples of a given animal, otherwise there's a little more work to do whenever retrieval takes place to arrive at a total.

I guess one could make the argument that the ID field isn't absolutely necessary for the animals either.  It could just be a lookup table of strings, though that requires a bit more space for storage and complicates things a little bit if you decide that you want to modify animal names for some reason.

Comment: Upvoted for being the only person to mention foreign keys so far. But primary key on that new table should be something like (UserID, AnimalID), and I'm sure the OP needs to know that, too.

Comment: @Catcall, thanks for the upvote.  The primary key on the table, of course, would depend upon whether the OP adds a Count column - obviously if there's no Count column and there's the requirement to have N dogs, for instance, we can't make the PK (UserID, AnimalID) - since there would be N rows at that point with the same UserID, AnimalID combo - probably would throw the one-up ID in there at that point, I think.  Though I might be inclined to go with the one with a Count field myself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you many to many relationship table.

Example:

```
table: users_x_animals
-----------------------
pid  |  u_id  |  a_id
1       2        3
2       4        5
3       2        5
4       7        1
5       4        2
```

This way if you have index (separate) on u_id and a_id you can either query for "animal with id X is owned by users" or the other way around "user with id x owns these animals".

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: If there can only be one of a type of animal for the user (Janet can have many animals, but only one rabbit) then you could remove the primary key column and make the u_id and a_id columns the primary key.

Comment: Yes, that is true, because primary keys are unique, I thought one user can add many animals of one kind, as for example I could have two cats "Jolie" and "Tom", I would love to add "cat" in my animals list twice, once for "Jolie" and once for "Tom". Up voted :)

Comment: The OP doesn't specify whether or not they need to support multiple types of the same animal...I modified my answer to use a Quantity column in the scenario that Janet can have 2 Rabbits.  Your solution would work with that scenario also, but I think a quanity column is better than counting rows for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, reducing the number of rows and data duplication is a big plus but if they need to name each animal I would prefer to stick with this one and just add 'a_name' column to the table instead of having another relation table for "relation_id, animal_name" :)